# What do badges icons represent on SO and should we change them

Tags: feature-request, badges

What do badges icons represent on Stack Overflow and on Super User?
Correct me if I'm wrong but these two site are the most visited ones and we still have the basic default pixelished badge icons. I think that the new top bar would be a good time to review the badges icons to make it look... better ?

Take a look at all these themed icons on the network :

Arquade have coins.

> [image]

Sci-Fi have StarWars looking badges.

> [image]

Math have geometrical forms.

> [image]

Programmers have a more polished version of those achievements.

> [image]

I say we try to find another cool idea that could fit Stack Overflow. Maybe little SO logos.

Comment: Or we could all just agree to have the Star Wars looking ones.

Comment: @TravisJ They're my favorite too !

Comment: What about sharp signs?

Comment: Or even just make them look like.... badges?